c++ probleme when compiling a basic programm using raylib
Hello I'm starting to learn c++ for game development purpose so I downloaded a template on GitHub that draw a ball, bouncing on the edge of the window like the "dvd logo" using the raylib library.
Unfortunately when i try to run the code (with no errors btw) the console shows up with a bunch of errors of undefined referenc.
here's the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <raylib.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    int ball_x = 100;
    int ball_y = 100;
    int ball_speed_x = 5;
    int ball_speed_y = 5;
    int ball_radius = 15;

    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    InitWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "My first RAYLIB program!");
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (WindowShouldClose() == false){
   
        ball_x += ball_speed_x;
        ball_y += ball_speed_y;

        if(ball_x + ball_radius >= SCREEN_WIDTH || ball_x - ball_radius <= 0)
        {
            ball_speed_x *= -1;
        }

        if(ball_y + ball_radius >= SCREEN_HEIGHT || ball_y - ball_radius <= 0)
        {
            ball_speed_y *= -1;
        }
        
        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(BLACK);
            DrawCircle(ball_x,ball_y,ball_radius, WHITE);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
}

And here's the errors in the console:
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGKPdYF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `InitWindow'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGKPdYF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `SetTargetFPS'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGKPdYF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `BeginDrawing'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGKPdYF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `ClearBackground'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGKPdYF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to `DrawCircle'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGKPdYF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x135): undefined reference to `EndDrawing'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGKPdYF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `WindowShouldClose'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I already try to install raylib manually using the installer on their website or with the MSYS2 command prompt or even change the location of the default include path but the error kept showing.
I'm really new to this C++ stuff and a bit lost, I hope you can help me and would appreciate any kind of help.
Thank you.

The real problem is likely above the lines of error that you show. The problem is most likely the command you typed to compile your code. If you are using VSCode remember that it does nothing at all to help you use an external library. Once you have an external library you must use CMake and the CMake tools extension, write a Makefile and use the Makefile tools extension or edit your tasks.json supplying the additional linker arguments to the args: section. VSCode will not do any of these for you automatically. You need to learn and do them yourself.

This is the misunderstanding that many beginners have. It is not enough to install the library, you must also tell your compiler that you want to use the library. How you do this depends on the compiler you are using, but clearly, whatever compiler that is, you are not doing it (or not doing it correctly).

It's clear from the question that you think that the only thing that matters here is the header files. The library is the header files. Again this is a common beginner misunderstanding, The header files are the interface for your code to the library. The library itself is a separate thing. If you forget to tell the compiler about the library you get undefined reference errors.

This might help

What you have is a linker error, not a compiler error. To use a Library you need to link it with your executable. See also What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?.
